# VB.Net How to get the ControlCollection items to show up in designer property grid?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-controls, designer

I have created a usercontrol with a panel inside it. This panel may have multiple other controls inside it.

I exposed this panel's controls through a ControlCollection property and set DesignerSerializationVisibility to Content.

However, I wish to show the collection items in the property panel instead of Control Collection Editor.

```
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
    Public ReadOnly Property CtlList As ControlCollection
        Get
            Return MyPanel.Controls
        End Get
    End Property
```

[Illustration output I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZwdB.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do?  Edit properties of existing controls?  Add/Remove controls to the UC? Whats not working right with what you have?

Comment: I want to access the panel's controls item directly from the property grid. As in the illustration output, I want TextEditor, Control1 and Control2 to be shown under EditorControl directly, thus you won't be able to add or remove the panel's controls item, but still able to edit their properties.

Comment: Thats not how it works.  VS compiles your UC in order to show it in the IDE.  The controls are generally fixed, though with a custom control designer you can add *specific* controls.  Note that the ones you apparently added via the collection editor are simply `Control`.  There arent anything specific like TextBox or CheckBox, just Control.  It also *sounds like* you want the form designer to drill into `Form.UC.Panel`  the form designer is for the form not the child of a child of the form

Comment: Hi @plutonix, thanks for your clarification. I thought there would be a way for IDE to know the types of controls I added just like in Control Collection Editor. If so I would just stick with what I have right now.